# HTML5 validation metadata

Tags: html, validation

So i've been surfing the web for half an hour and I could not find anything that would help with this error

Line 5, Column 269: Element meta is missing one or more of the following attributes: http-equiv, itemprop, name, property.
… Javascript and you will not be able to operate the site without Javascript" />
Attributes for element meta:
Global attributes
name
http-equiv
content
charset

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my meta tags? 

My relevant code is below:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="etc etc info" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
<meta name="author"  content="my name" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `<meta content="etc etc info" />` for? I guess it should be something like `<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr." />`

You only provide the value for something, but with no name. So the browser doesn't know what this is for. You can find some more meta examples on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) or many other sites.